# Unittest in Python returning False despite tests OK?

Tags: python

My code:

```
import unittest
from mylib import myfunc

class test_mylib(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_myfunc(self):
        self.assertTrue(myfunc(10)==50)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

It shows the test as OK, but then returns False at the same time. Is there a way for it to return True if the tests are OK?

Output:

```
OK
Exit code:  False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Unix, the process exit code `0` means success. I guess whatever tool you're using to run the tests is interpreting that as `False`.